# Is it possible to retrieve phone's color theme?

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors, resources, themes, appsettings

Depending on the phone brand, windows phone users can choose between more or less twenty colors. When they do, it  directly changes the color of the main tiles. Since this setting must be stored somewhere, I was wondering if we could get access to it.

What I'd like to do, is a way to set this preference as a ressource for my app. That way, anytime a user change his color theme, the next time he opens the app, it will automatically be colored like his phone.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code behind:

```
PhoneApplicatonPage pap = new PhoneApplicationPage();
pap.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]).ToString();
```

In XAML:

```
{StaticResource PhoneForegroundColor}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Looks easy enough

Comment: Why not use `PhoneAccentBrush`?